# Grammar: subordinate clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I am trying to improve my English writing skills. I want to say the following sentence to my friend on phone. Is the below sentence grammatically and logically correct?

> Yesterday late night rain made the playing area so wet that umpires have to call off today’s play.

Is "umpires have to call off today’s play" considered a subordinate clause? Will the clause starting from relative pronoun is always used as an adjective clause?

Comment: You're talking about something that happened in the past, so you need to say *umpires **had to** call off...*

Comment: @Ustanak That's probably what OP means; but it's also possible that this is being said at the very time the umpires are winding up their inspection of the ground.

Comment: "Yesterday late night" is not idiomatic. We don't say "yesterday night" but "last night"; so you want "late last night".

Comment: @Colin: If we accept [They still prefer the **cooling night rain** to the bright, hot glare of the sun](http://www.si.com/vault/1956/10/22/670458/miami-turns-night-into-day) as a reasonable usage, I can't see why ***late** night rain* shouldn't be equally acceptable. But this is probably just a potentially confusing rather than helpful observation in the context of learners.

Comment: @ColinFine Many persons actually **do** say "yesterday night," cf "yesterday week," "tomorrow fortnight," etc. But of course that is not the meaning here, which is "Yesterday, late at night, rain made the playing area wet."

Comment: @P.E.Dant: You're right, and I'm (partly) wrong: "Yesterday night" is idiomatic, alongside "last night". But "Yesterday late night" isn't. However, FumbleFingers has suggested that it might parse as "yesterday, [late night rain]", which hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are correct in identifying *that umpires have to call off today’s play* as a subordinate clause.
2. It is not, however, a *relative* clause. This *that* is not a relative pronoun; if it were, it could be replaced with *which*. It is, rather, a marker of subordination (a *subordinating conjunction* in traditional grammar, or *subordinator* in the neo-traditionalist approach of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*). *That* has at least three different uses: as a relative pronoun (but *CGEL* denies that *that* is a relative pronoun), as a subordinator, and as a demonstrative pronoun, and you can only tell which one is play by the context.  Here it marks the clause which completes the *so ... that ...* comparative construction, so it might be called a *complementizer*, too.
3. A clause launched by a relative pronoun may act as an adjectival or a nominal:

   > ADJ: The word which you want is on page 238.
   >   NOM: You have to decide which word you want.

   It's an open question whether these relatives are the same words as the identical forms employed as interrogatives:

   > Which word do you want?

   Clauses launched by other relatives (e.g., *where*, *when*, *whether*, *why*, how*) may act as nominals, adjectivals or adverbials—or, if your grammatical sect permits, interrogatives.

Answer (score 1):

In your example **that** is a conjunction and introduces a circumstantial or modal subordinate clause. The pattern **so + adjective/adverb + that** typically expresses a cause and effect relationship.

[Note](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/sosuch.html) that the **that** is optional.

Comment: I think this is a comparative construction rather than an adverbial of purpose.

Comment: I disagree, @StoneyB. There is an implied comparison, yes, but the _that_ clause is not the standard of comparison, but the action justified by the comparison.

Comment: @ColinFine W e l l ... I'd say that the *that* clause is the *measure* of ADJ. In any case, what I'm concerned with is that *so ADJ that S* not be misconstrued as a variant of *so that S*. (I hate writing about *that*; it always seems to involve so many *that*s that are not the *that* I'm writing about.)

Comment: I see what you mean, @StoneyB. But in that sentence it strongly implies that they actual did call off (or are calling off) play, so pragmatically it is much more than a measure.